# Sorting arrays with Radixsort

Tags: arrays, algorithm, radix-sort

I am currently trying to understand Radixsort and therefor i have a short question.

What I think is very bad to sort with Radixsort, is the array below:

**"9999...9, 9999...9, 9999...9"**

Because Radixsort will compare every single number of the first, second and third number in the array. So it would be better to use another sortingalgorithm for this array. I am right or are there other arrays which are very disadvantageous to sort with Radixsort?

Best regards

Comment: Radix sort isn't based on comparing elements against each other, so I'm not sure how you reach your conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time cost of a radix sort is O(nm) where n is the number of elements and m is the complexity of the elements.  You are right, there are instances where it is not faster.  With long integer strings, m can exceed logn which nlogn would be the time cost of a merge sort for example.